# How many values can $y/n_2-x/n_1$ take given $n_2, n_1$ are positive integers and coprime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $X \in \{0,\dots,n_1\}$ and $Y \in \{0,\dots,n_2\}$, with $n_1,n_2 \in \mathbf{N}$ and coprime. Then form the random variable $$\frac{Y}{n_2}-\frac{X}{n_1} \ .$$ How many values can it take?

What does coprime imply in this specific case?

Comment: Coprime means $\gcd(n_1, n_2) = 1$, which means they have no factors in common other than $1$.

Comment: Does this mean that the random variable made up of $Y$ and $X$ only takes unique values for each value $X$ and $Y$ take respectively?

Comment: Yeah, you've got it - the only exception is when the random variable is equal to $0$, which can occur in two ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following equation with the numerator in the required ranges:
$$\frac{Y_1}{n_2}-\frac{X_1}{n_1}=\frac{Y_2}{n_2}-\frac{X_2}{n_1}$$
Then, we have:
$$(Y_1-Y_2)n_1=(X_1-X_2)n_2$$
This is where the condition of co-primality comes into play. We must have $n_1$ dividing $X_1-X_2$. From the fact that $0 \leqslant X \leqslant n_1$, this is only possible if $X_1=X_2$ (which in turn forces $Y_1=Y_2$), or if one of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is $n_1$ and the other is $0$. In the latter case, it is similarly forced that one of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ is $n_2$ and the other is $0$ (they cannot be equal as the values of $X$ are unequal). We can indeed see that the pairs $(X,Y)=(n_1,n_2),(0,0)$ give the same output. The significant fact is that we have proven this to be the only pair to give the same output. The total number of pairs is $(n_1+1)(n_2+1)$. Hence,  excluding one of the two pairs which give the same output yields the answer:
$$(n_1+1)(n_2+1)-1=n_1n_2+n_1+n_2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$z = \frac{Y}{n_2} - \frac{X}{n_1} = \frac{n_1Y - n_2X}{n_1n_2}$$

Since $n_1$ and $n_2$ are coprime, there is no factor you can pull out of the $n$ terms on the numerator and denominator to cancel things out into a smaller-looking fraction with the same value - any change in how the fraction looks will be entirely due to $X$ and $Y$.

It makes the counting easier, because otherwise there are multiple ways to get a particular value $z$ and the problem becomes more complicated. This way the only "tricky" case is when $z = 0$ (which can happen in two ways: When $X=Y=0$, and when $X=n_1, Y=n_2$) - every other value is achieved uniquely.